# Creating a dynamic form in php

Tags: php, html, forms, web

I am trying to create a dynamic HTML form where the fields displayed are based on inputs in the field above it. So far, I have only found resources that work in JS but I was wondering if there was a pure PHP way to do it.

To give some context: I would like to create a form for a user to set their goal. The 'How Much' and 'programme duration' fields are dependent on the 'goal type' field. Ie. if They choose a muscle building goal then it will only show 5% etc. Here is my code so far...

Much appreciated in advanced!

```
<?php
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
   
?>


<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please set your goal and programme type</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="Set_Goal_process.php" >
            
            <label for="Sex"><b>Sex: </b></label>
            <select name="Sex" id="Sex" required>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
            
            <label for="Age"><b>Age: </b></label>
            <input type="number" name="Age" id="Age" value="Age" required>

            <label for="Height"><b>Height: </b></label>
            <input type="number" name="Height" id="Height" required>
            
            <label for="Current Weight"><b>Current Weight: </b></label>
            <input type="number" name="Initial_weight" id="Initial Weight" required>       

            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <label for="Activity level"><b>Activity level: </b></label>
            <select name="Activity_level" id="Activity level" required>
                <option value=1>Sedentary</option>
                <option value=2>Mostly sedentary</option>
                <option value=3>Lightly active</option>
                <option value=4>Highly active</option>
            </select>

            <label for="Goal type"><b>Goal type: </b></label>
            <select name="Goal_type" id="Goal type" required>
                <option value=1>Fat Loss</option>
                <option value=2>Maintenance</option>
                <option value=3>Muscle Building</option>
            </select>
            
            <label for="How much"><b>How much: </b></label>
            <select name="How_much" id="How much" default="0" required>
                <option value=-10>-10%</option>
                <option value=-7.5>-7.5%</option>
                <option value=-5>-5%</option>
                <option value=-2.5>-2.5%</option>
                <option value=0 selected>0%</option>
                <option value=2.5>2.5%</option>
                <option value=5>5%</option>
            </select>
            
            <!-- comment make both How much and program duration conditional -->
            <label for="Program Duration"><b>Program Duration: </b></label>
            <select name="Program_duration" id="Program Duration" required>
                <option value=4>4 weeks</option>
                <option value=8>8 weeks</option>
                <option value=12 selected>12 weeks</option>
            </select>
            
            <label for="Experience_level"><b>Experience level: </b></label>
            <select name="Expereince_level" id="Expereince level" required>
                <option value=1 selected>Beginner</option>
                <option value=2>Novice</option>
                <option value=3 >Intermediate</option>
                <option value=4 >Advanced</option>
            </select>    
            
            <label for="Sessions per week">Sessions per week:</label>
            <input type="number" name="Sessions_per_week" id="Sessions per week" min="1" max="7" required>
            <label for="Start date">Start date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="Start date"id="Start date" >

            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Get Started!"required>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>

<?php
}else {
             session_destroy();
            header("location: index.php");
            
        }
```

Comment: Very Nice. Good Luck !

Comment: Sure it's possible. For it to work, you need to submit the form (which will do a new page reload) and then render what you need depending on what the user submitted. Imho, it makes much more sense to do this in JS (since you then can do it without the need to submit the form, making it way more user friendly) so I would recommend looking at those JS solutions you found. Either way, you need to make some attempts yourself first.